# UITableViewCell Frame Doesn't change after i set in first load

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a custom **UITableViewCell** with **xib** and add in few UILabel into **xib**. After that i created my own function to set the frame of the UILabel.

**In View Controller:**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

ListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

[cell setLabelFrame:self.labelFloor.frame
                unit:self.labelUnit.frame
                type:self.labelType.frame
                sqft:self.labelsqft.frame
               price:self.labelPrice.frame
              facing:self.labelFacing.frame
                view:self.labelView.frame
              status:self.labelStatus.frame
         labelHeight:labelHeight];
    }
```

**IN ListTableViewCell:**

```
- (void)setLabelFrame:(CGRect)floor
             unit:(CGRect)unit
             type:(CGRect)type
             sqft:(CGRect)sqft
            price:(CGRect)price
           facing:(CGRect)facing
             view:(CGRect)view
           status:(CGRect)status
      labelHeight:(CGFloat)labelHeight {

float pointX = 0;
CGFloat fontSize = 13;

// Create Floor label
pointX = floor.origin.x;
[self.lb_floor setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, floor.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_floor setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_floor.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_floor setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Unit label
pointX = unit.origin.x;
[self.lb_unit setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, unit.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_unit setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_unit.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_unit setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Type Label
pointX = type.origin.x;
[self.lb_type setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, type.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_type setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_type.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_type setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Sq.Ft. Label
pointX = sqft.origin.x;
[self.lb_sqft setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, sqft.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_sqft setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_sqft.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_sqft setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Price Label
pointX = price.origin.x;
[self.lb_price setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, price.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_price setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_price.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_price setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Facing Label
pointX = facing.origin.x;
[self.lb_facing setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, facing.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_facing setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_facing.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_facing setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create View Label
pointX = view.origin.x;
[self.lb_view setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, view.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_view setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_view.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_view setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

// Create Status Label
pointX = status.origin.x;
[self.lb_status setFrame:CGRectMake(pointX, 0, status.size.width, labelHeight)];
[self.lb_status setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
self.lb_status.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
[self.lb_status setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:fontSize]];

 }
```

The problem is, it doesn't change the label frame as i specific in the first load, it changes after i scrolling. How should i refresh it in first laod.

**Updated With Images**

1. [First Load](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sf378fzhxcd55yk/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Mar%2030%2C%202015%2C%202.34.32%20PM.png?dl=0)
2. [After Scrolling](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c2avk59azzhsdln/iOS%20Simulator%20Screen%20Shot%20Mar%2030%2C%202015%2C%202.34.48%20PM.png?dl=0)

Comment: I think whatever u had set the frame of label through xib it gets displayed 1st & then programmatically setted frame will get set .Try to set your programmatically setted frame through xib only. & the frame,font size  of label through xib & through programmatically  may be differ.

Comment: setting in xib should work right, but what i want is to set it dynamically.

Comment: if u want to set it dynamically then create cell programmatically only, no need of xib is there.

Comment: you are right, but i dont think it will solve my problem

Comment: Well on the first hand you shouldn't be touching frames if you are using autolayout. Or else disable autolayout in your xib and then you can set frames programmatically.

Comment: Wow, disable auto layout works. Why will it happened? Such a genius @Burhanuddin Sunelwala

Comment: read my edited answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your method above write the following in the end

```
- (void)setLabelFrame:(CGRect)floor
             unit:(CGRect)unit
             type:(CGRect)type
             sqft:(CGRect)sqft
            price:(CGRect)price
           facing:(CGRect)facing
             view:(CGRect)view
           status:(CGRect)status
      labelHeight:(CGFloat)labelHeight {

     //setting of frames...
     .
     .
     .
     [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

if AutoLayout is enabled, then use

```
[self updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```

Well on the first hand you shouldn't be touching frames if you are using autolayout. The whole point of using AutoLayout is that frames are inferred based on the satisfiable constraints attached to them.

Or else disable autolayout in your xib and then you can set frames programmatically.

I suggest you should read more on how to use constraints and then you wouldn't be needing to write this whole code for setting frames. AutoLayout would just do that for you.

[AutoLayout in iOS7](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout?

Comment: The UILabel doesn't has autoLayout

Comment: No, my question is, does your xib file have AutoLayout enabled?

Comment: then you need to use updateConstraintsIfNeeded. Let me know if it works

Answer (score -1):

I hope your cellForRowAtIndexPath should be like this-

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {
        ListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ListCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        if(cell == nil)
        {
            NSString *nibName = @"ListTableViewCell";
            cell = (ListTableViewCell *)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] lastObject];
        }

        [cell setLabelFrame:self.labelFloor.frame
                        unit:self.labelUnit.frame
                        type:self.labelType.frame
                        sqft:self.labelsqft.frame
                       price:self.labelPrice.frame
                      facing:self.labelFacing.frame
                        view:self.labelView.frame
                      status:self.labelStatus.frame
                 labelHeight:labelHeight];

        [cell layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Please ensure you are calling your setLabelFrame in both cases

Case 1) Cell created for the first time

case 2) Using dequeue cell

Comment: dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: will either return a valid cell or crash, so there's no reason for an if(cell ==nil) clause; it never will be nil. If the cell is made in a xib, then you should register the nib in viewDidLoad.

Comment: i did register in viewDidLoad