# Increase UIView size not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have a NSArray of UIViews, and i am trying to increase the size of all of them, i am using the below but it is not working?

```
for (UIView *view in self.viewArray) {

    int rndValue = 1 + arc4random() % (360 - 1);
    view.layer.affineTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(rndValue);

    CGRect newFrame = view.frame;

    newFrame.size.width = 600;
    newFrame.size.height = 600;
    [view setFrame:newFrame];
}
```

Any ideas? the rotate works but not increase.  Might the constraints in storyboard be stopping it from working?

Comment: If you remove the constraints from the storyboard and run it does it work? (make a copy of your project if you need to)

Comment: Can you try call [view setNeedsDisplay]; after you set frame?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29338739/2099097

Comment: you need to adjust view according to auto layout constraint as view doesn't update on auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't mix Auto Layout with setting frame sizes manually.

In your Storyboard map the constraints you want to change to IBOutlets and then change those programmatically instead.